# CentOS 7: Fresh Install Firewalld doesn't work at all (Fatal Error: No IPv4 and IPv6 firewall)

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld, systemctl

I have the following problem.

I just did an DVD CenOS 7 installation. After I boot into the system I normally login as the root user. From there I'm trying to configure Firewall on my server.

As I'm relatively new to all of this I just did some search on how to start and manage Firewalld which seems to be the intended firewall software to use with CentOS 7.

The first thing I tried was typing

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

As output I get

```
Warning: iptables not usable, disabling IPv4 firewall.
Warning: ip6tables not usable, disabling IPv6 firewall.
FATAL ERROR: No IPv4 and IPv6 firewall.
ERROR: Raising SystemExit in run_server
```

I already tried rebooting the system, updating it. I reinstalled both iptables and firewalld. Tried it with either of which being masked or disable. None of this has worked but maybe I missed something.

I generally just wanted to setup a Teamspeak server for outside use which worked under Windows when I added a specific rule to the firewall. I wanted to do the same under CentOS 7 mostly for learning purposes or to get familiar with Linux as server at all.

Comment: Try to use `iptables-save` or `iptables -L` to check if your kernel supports iptables.

Comment: Exactly what is this "server"?

Comment: From iptables -L i get `iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table 'filter' : Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)`

Comment: It is a CentOS 7 server running on a barebone x686 architecture machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check your kernel version with `uname -a` command,
If your version is below 3.10, update your kernel, reboot your system and you should be fine.